Ubuntu 24.04 : nuplot: symbol lookup error: gnuplot: undefined symbol: _ZTI10wxListBase, version WXU_3.2
Since it is looking for the dynamic library for wxWidgets 3.2/Unicode, I read here : https://www.wxwidgets.org/downloads/ that DLLs for the selected compilers are available, and binaries for common Linux distributions are also available
https://docs.codelite.org/wxWidgets/repo320/
But I get this this output:
raphy@raohy:~$ sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://repos.codelite.org/wx3.2.0/ubuntu/ jammy universe'
Repository: 'deb https://repos.codelite.org/wx3.2.0/ubuntu/ jammy universe'
Description:
Archive for codename: jammy components: universe
More info: https://repos.codelite.org/wx3.2.0/ubuntu/
Adding repository.
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel.
Found existing deb entry in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_repos_codelite_org_wx3_2_0_ubuntu_-noble.list
Adding deb entry to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_repos_codelite_org_wx3_2_0_ubuntu_-noble.list
Found existing deb-src entry in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_repos_codelite_org_wx3_2_0_ubuntu_-noble.list
Adding disabled deb-src entry to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_repos_codelite_org_wx3_2_0_ubuntu_-noble.list
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease
Ign:2 https://repos.codelite.org/wx3.2.0/ubuntu noble InRelease                                                                                
Ign:3 https://repos.codelite.org/wx3.2.0/ubuntu numbat InRelease                                                                               
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease                                                                  
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease                       
Hit:6 https://repos.codelite.org/wx3.2.0/ubuntu jammy InRelease     
Err:7 https://repos.codelite.org/wx3.2.0/ubuntu noble Release                                   
  404  Not Found [IP: 79.143.189.67 443]
Err:8 https://repos.codelite.org/wx3.2.0/ubuntu numbat Release                                  
  404  Not Found [IP: 79.143.189.67 443]
Hit:9 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu noble InRelease
Hit:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease                
Hit:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease        
Hit:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease
Hit:13 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://repos.codelite.org/wx3.2.0/ubuntu noble Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'https://repos.codelite.org/wx3.2.0/ubuntu numbat Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: https://repos.codelite.org/wx3.2.0/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'https://repos.codelite.org/wx3.2.0/ubuntu jammy InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386

Update 01)
I removed from the /apt/ repo the references to the jammy release, since it's Ubuntu 24.05
I've searched for wxwidgets library Ubuntu packages and found these ones:
raphy@raohy:~$ sudo apt-cache search wxWidgets
python3-pyudev - Python3 bindings for libudev
bossa - Atmel SAM ARM microcontroller flash programming GUI
codeblocks-contrib - contrib plugins for Code::Blocks IDE
erlang-wx - Erlang/OTP bindings to wxWidgets
filezilla - Full-featured graphical FTP/FTPS/SFTP client
filezilla-common - Architecture independent files for filezilla
libalien-wxwidgets-perl - Perl module for locating wxWidgets binaries
libplplotwxwidgets1 - Scientific plotting library (wxWidgets bindings)
libwx-glcanvas-perl - Perl interface to wxWidgets' OpenGL canvas
libwx-perl - interface to wxWidgets cross-platform GUI toolkit
libwx-scintilla-perl - source code editor component for wxWidgets
libwxbase3.2-1t64 - wxBase library (runtime) - non-GUI support classes of wxWidgets toolkit
libwxgtk-gl3.2-1t64 - wxWidgets Cross-platform C++ GUI toolkit (GTK 3 gl library runtime)
libwxgtk-media3.2-1t64 - wxWidgets Cross-platform C++ GUI toolkit (GTK 3 media library runtime)
libwxgtk-media3.2-dev - wxWidgets Cross-platform C++ GUI toolkit (GTK 3 media library development)
libwxgtk-webview3.2-1t64 - wxWidgets Cross-platform C++ GUI toolkit (GTK 3 webview library runtime)
libwxgtk-webview3.2-dev - wxWidgets Cross-platform C++ GUI toolkit (GTK 3 webview library development)
libwxgtk3.2-1t64 - wxWidgets Cross-platform C++ GUI toolkit (GTK 3 runtime)
libwxgtk3.2-dev - wxWidgets Cross-platform C++ GUI toolkit (GTK 3 development)
libwxsqlite3-3.2-0t64 - SQLite3 C++ wrapper for use in programs based on the wxWidgets
libwxsqlite3-3.2-dev - Development files for wxSQLite3
libwxsvg-dev - Development files for wxSVG
libwxsvg-tools - SVG library for the wxWidgets toolkit (tools)
libwxsvg3t64 - SVG library for the wxWidgets toolkit
openbabel-gui - Chemical toolbox utilities (graphical user interface)
plplot-driver-wxwidgets - Scientific plotting library (wxWidgets driver)
poedit - gettext catalog editor
poedit-common - Common files for poedit
python3-dsv - Python module for delimiter-separated-value files (Python 3)
python3-wxgtk-media4.0 - Python 3 interface to the wxWidgets Cross-platform C++ GUI toolkit (wx.media)
python3-wxgtk-webview4.0 - Python 3 interface to the wxWidgets Cross-platform C++ GUI toolkit (wx.html2)
python3-wxgtk4.0 - Python 3 interface to the wxWidgets Cross-platform C++ GUI toolkit
silverjuke - jukebox, karaoke, and kiosk mode mp3 player
survex-aven - sophisticated cave survey viewer for Survex
wx-common - wxWidgets Cross-platform C++ GUI toolkit (common support files)
wx3.2-doc - wxWidgets Cross-platform C++ GUI toolkit (documentation)
wx3.2-examples - wxWidgets Cross-platform C++ GUI toolkit (examples)
wx3.2-headers - wxWidgets Cross-platform C++ GUI toolkit (header files)
wx3.2-i18n - wxWidgets Cross-platform C++ GUI toolkit (i18n support)
wxedid - Graphical editor for monitor resolution and timing data (EDID)
wxglade - GUI designer written in Python with wxPython
wxpython-tools - Tools from the wxPython distribution
wxsqlite3-doc - Documentation files for wxSQLite3

And libwxgtk3.2-dev is already present :
raphy@raohy:~$ sudo apt-get install libwxgtk3.2-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
libwxgtk3.2-dev is already the newest version (3.2.4+dfsg-4build1).

Update 02)
I checked the installed version of gnuplot :
raphy@raohy:~$ sudo apt-cache search gnuplot
bonnie++ - Hard drive benchmark suite
devscripts - scripts to make the life of a Debian Package maintainer easier
amanda-client - Advanced Maryland Automatic Network Disk Archiver (Client)
amanda-server - Advanced Maryland Automatic Network Disk Archiver (Server)
c2x - converter between DFT electronic structure codes formats
cdck - tool for verifying the quality of written CDs/DVDs
chiark-scripts - chiark system administration scripts
circos - plotter for visualizing data
collectl - Utility to collect Linux performance data
colplot - Utility to plot performance data from collectl
context-modules - additional ConTeXt modules
ctioga2 - polymorphic plotting program
elpa-gnuplot-mode - Gnuplot mode for Emacs
feedgnuplot - Pipe-oriented frontend to Gnuplot
flowgrind - Distributed network performance measurement tool
gausssum - parse and display Gaussian, GAMESS, and etc's output
gnuplot - Command-line driven interactive plotting program.
gnuplot-data - Command-line driven interactive plotting program. Data-files
gnuplot-doc - Command-line driven interactive plotting program. Doc-package
gnuplot-mode - Transition Package, gnuplot-mode to elpa-gnuplot-mode
gnuplot-nox - Command-line driven interactive plotting program. No-X package
gnuplot-qt - Command-line driven interactive plotting program. QT-package
gnuplot-x11 - Command-line driven interactive plotting program. X-package
hershey-font-gnuplot - Hershey vector fonts renderer for gnuplot
jed-extra - collection of useful Jed modes and utilities
libalien-gnuplot-perl - module to find and validate the gnuplot executable
libchart-gnuplot-perl - module for generating two- and three-dimensional plots
libfinance-bank-ie-permanenttsb-perl - perl interface to the PermanentTSB Open24 homebanking
libgnuplot-iostream-dev - C++ programming interface for gnuplot. Headers
libgnuplot-iostream-doc - C++ programming interface for gnuplot. Docs and examples
libgnuplot-ocaml-dev - OCaml interface to the gnuplot utility
libgraph-writer-dsm-perl - Perl module to draw Graph object as a DSM matrix
libgraphics-gnuplotif-perl - dynamic Perl interface to gnuplot
libpdl-graphics-gnuplot-perl - gnuplot-based plotting backend for PDL
libploticus0 - script driven business graphics library
libploticus0-dev - Development files for the ploticus library
librust-gnuplot-dev - Rust gnuplot controller - Rust source code
librust-malachite-base-dev - Collection of utilities, including new arithmetic traits and iterators that generate all values of a type - Rust source code
mathomatic - portable Computer Algebra System (CAS)
octave-plplot - Octave support for PLplot, a plotting library
ploticus - script driven business graphics package
probcons-extra - Extra programs from the probcons package
pstoedit - PostScript and PDF files to editable vector graphics converter
python3-gnuplot - Python interface to the gnuplot plotting program
python3-gnuplotlib - Gnuplot-based plotter for numpy
python3-pygnuplot - Simple Python wrapper for Gnuplot
rheolef - efficient Finite Element environment
rubber - automated system for building LaTeX documents
ruby-gnuplot - Ruby library to interact with gnuplot
stda - simple tools for data analysis (stda)
tcptrace - Tool for analyzing tcpdump output
texlive-latex-extra - TeX Live: LaTeX additional packages
texlive-pictures - TeX Live: Graphics, pictures, diagrams
texlive-science - TeX Live: Mathematics, natural sciences, computer science packages
raphy@raohy:~$ 

gnuplot is already the newest version :
raphy@raohy:~$ sudo apt-get install gnuplot
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
gnuplot is already the newest version (6.0.0+dfsg1-1ubuntu3).

Installed  libgnuplot-iostream-dev :
raphy@raohy:~$ sudo apt-get install libgnuplot-iostream-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libgav1-1 libyuv0 linux-objects-nvidia-470-6.5.0-44-generic linux-signatures-nvidia-6.5.0-44-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
Suggested packages:
  libgnuplot-iostream-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libgnuplot-iostream-dev
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 19 not upgraded.
Need to get 19,3 kB of archives.
After this operation, 87,0 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/universe amd64 libgnuplot-iostream-dev all 0~20140302.gitc8919a0+dfsg-4 [19,3 kB]
Fetched 19,3 kB in 0s (49,7 kB/s)                  
Selecting previously unselected package libgnuplot-iostream-dev.
(Reading database ... 501326 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libgnuplot-iostream-dev_0~20140302.gitc8919a0+dfsg-4_all.deb ...
Unpacking libgnuplot-iostream-dev (0~20140302.gitc8919a0+dfsg-4) ...
Setting up libgnuplot-iostream-dev (0~20140302.gitc8919a0+dfsg-4) ...

But still get the same error:
raphy@raohy:~$ gnuplot
gnuplot: symbol lookup error: gnuplot: undefined symbol: 
_ZTI10wxListBase, version WXU_3.2

Update 03)
raphy@raohy:~$ which gnuplot
/usr/bin/gnuplot

raphy@raohy:~$ dpkg -S $(realpath $(which gnuplot))
gnuplot-x11: /usr/bin/gnuplot-x11

What should I install then?
OS: Ubuntu 24.04 Desktop
Any suggestions on how to solve this issue?

Jammy is not Ubuntu 24.04 you need to review your info and sources files. Your question looks like you have mixed 2 different version of Ubuntu  source files.

Hi @DavidDE ! You are right. I mixed them up. I cleaned the /apt/ repo, and searched fr wxWidgets DLL in Ubuntu Official Repo. libwxgtk3.2-dev is already present. What should I install then? : see Update 1) in my post above

If you installed gnuplot via apt, then it should have pulled in all the required dependencies automatically - in particular, libwxbase3.2-1t64 (which includes the libwx_baseu-3.2.so.0.2.2 DLL, which is where the _ZTI10wxListBase symbol should be found). You should not need any development (-dev) packages.

@steeldriver I checked, and the installed gnuplot is already the newest version. I installed also libgnuplot-iostream-dev package. But I stil get the same error : raphy@raohy:~$ gnuplot gnuplot: symbol lookup error: gnuplot: undefined symbol: _ZTI10wxListBase, version WXU_3.2  . I updated my post above with Update 02)

Please confirm the origin of gnuplot that you installed - for example which gnuplot and dpkg -S $(realpath $(which gnuplot)). As I mentioned before, you should not need any -dev packages - the package that provides the relevant library (assuming you installed one of gnuplot-x11, gnuplot-nox, or gnuplot-qt from the Ubuntu noble repository) is libwxbase3.2-1t64.

@steeldriver : raphy@raohy:~$ dpkg -S $(realpath $(which gnuplot)) gnuplot-x11: /usr/bin/gnuplot-x11 . And raphy@raohy:~$ which gnuplot /usr/bin/gnuplot . I updated my post above with Update 03)

So I guess the remaining possibilities are (1) gnuplot is aliased to something other than plain /usr/bin/gnuplot (check with type -a gnuplot) or (2) it is linking to some other libwx_baseu library (check with ldd $(realpath $(which gnuplot)) | grep libwx for example) or (3) your libwx_baseu library really does not define the symbol (check with nm -D /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwx_baseu-3.2.so.0.2.2 | grep _ZTI10wxListBase assuming an x86_64 architecture with the current libwxbase3.2-1t64 package)

I want to thank @steeldriver and @DavidDE for their suggestions and help
I solved the issue compiling and installing ex novo, from scratch, again, both wxWidgets and gnuplot
Steps followed:
Step 1a :
raphy@raohy:~$ git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets.git

Step 1b :
raphy@raohy:~$ cd wxWidgets/
raphy@raohy:~/wxWidgets$ mkdir build-gtk
raphy@raohy:~/wxWidgets$ cd build-gtk/
raphy@raohy:~/wxWidgets/build-gtk$ 

raphy@raohy:~/wxWidgets/build-gtk$ ../configure --with-gtk=3

Step 1c :
raphy@raohy:~/wxWidgets/build-gtk$ make -j4

Step 1d :
raphy@raohy:~/wxWidgets/build-gtk$ sudo make install

Step 2a:
raphy@raohy:~$ git clone https://git.code.sf.net/p/gnuplot/gnuplot-main gnuplot-gnuplot-main

Step 2b :
raphy@raohy:~$ cd gnuplot-gnuplot-main/
raphy@raohy:~/gnuplot-gnuplot-main$ 
raphy@raohy:~/gnuplot-gnuplot-main$ ./prepare

Step 3b  :
raphy@raohy:~/gnuplot-gnuplot-main$ ./configure --with-wx=/home/max/Desktop/wxWidgets/build-gtk/ --with-qt=no

Step 3c :
raphy@raohy:~/gnuplot-gnuplot-main$ make

Step 3d :
raphy@raohy:~/gnuplot-gnuplot-main$ make check


Step 3e :
raphy@raohy:~/gnuplot-gnuplot-main$ sudo make install

But there is something strange left to understand... :
I compiled and run a simple example of Matplotplusplus and, again, that kind of error appeared:
raphy@raohy:~/Plotting$ cmake -B builddir
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 12.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 13.2.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done (0.3s)
-- Generating done (0.0s)
-- Build files have been written to: /home/raphy/Plotting/builddir
raphy@raohy:~/Plotting$ 
raphy@raohy:~/Plotting$ cmake --build builddir
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Plotting.dir/src/plot3_1.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable Plotting
[100%] Built target Plotting
raphy@raohy:~/Plotting$ ./builddir/Plotting 
gnuplot: symbol lookup error: gnuplot: undefined symbol: _ZN8wxCursorD1Ev, version WXU_3.3
raphy@raohy:~/Plotting$ gnuplot
gnuplot: symbol lookup error: gnuplot: undefined symbol: _ZN8wxCursorD1Ev, version WXU_3.3

This is the CMakeLists.txt :
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(Plotting)

find_package(Matplot++ REQUIRED)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
    src/plot3_1.cpp
)

target_link_libraries (${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
    Matplot++::matplot
)

And this is the source file raphy@raohy:~/Plotting$ nano ./src/plot3_1.cpp :
#include <cmath>
#include <matplot/matplot.h>

int main() {
    using namespace matplot;
    std::vector<double> t = iota(0, pi / 50, 10 * pi);
    std::vector<double> st = transform(t, [](auto x) { return sin(x); });
    std::vector<double> ct = transform(t, [](auto x) { return cos(x); });
    auto l = plot3(st, ct, t);
    show();
    return 0;
}

And now, just executing gnuplot, gives that error :
raphy@raohy:~/Plotting$ gnuplot
gnuplot: symbol lookup error: gnuplot: undefined symbol: _ZN8wxCursorD1Ev, version WXU_3.3

But, after re-doing these steps for gnuplot:
raphy@raohy:~/gnuplot-gnuplot-main$ ./prepare
plot-main$ ./configure --with-wx=/home/max/Desktop/wxWidgets/build-gtk/ --with-qt=no
raphy@raohy:~/gnuplot-gnuplot-main$ make
raphy@raohy:~/gnuplot-gnuplot-main$ sudo make install

gnuplot works, again, fine:
    G N U P L O T
    Version 6.1 patchlevel 0    last modified 2024-07-26

    Copyright (C) 1986-1993, 1998, 2004, 2007-2024
    Thomas Williams, Colin Kelley and many others

    gnuplot home:     http://www.gnuplot.info
    mailing list:     gnuplot-beta@lists.sourceforge.net
    faq, bugs, etc:   type "help FAQ"
    immediate help:   type "help"  (plot window: hit 'h')

    Terminal type is now wxt
gnuplot> 

And the Matplotplusplus simple example works fine as well :
raphy@raohy:~/Plotting$ cmake --build builddir
[100%] Built target Plotting
raphy@raohy:~/Plotting$ ./builddir/Plotting 


I'm really astonished ....
It seems that the only gnuplot present is the one installed one hour ago:
raphy@raohy:~$ which gnuplot
/usr/local/bin/gnuplot
raphy@raohy:~$ ls -lah /usr/local/bin/gnuplot 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 7,3M lug 30 12:48 /usr/local/bin/gnuplot

What could interfere with the correct functioning of gnuplot ?

If you have a new question, ask it separately using the Ask Question button.
